# What is the limit of autocorrelation of ARIMA(1,1,0) series

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

Consider the causal AR(1) time-series $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + w_t$ such that $x_{t} - x_{t-1} = y_t$. I want to compute the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} corr(x_t, x_{2t})$.

It is easy so see that the ACF of $y_t$ is $\rho(h) = corr(y_t, y_{t+h}) = \sigma_w^2 \phi^h\frac{1}{1-\phi^2}$. Therefore, for fixed $t$, translate $\{x_t\}$ such that $x_{t-1} = 0$ (we can do this because covariance is invariante unter adding constant). Thus $$corr(x_t, x_{2t}) = corr(y_t, \sum_{n =t}^{2t}y_t)=\frac{cov(\sum_{n =t}^{2t}y_t, y_t)}{cov(\sum_{n =t}^{2t}y_t, \sum_{n =t}^{2t}y_t)\gamma_y(0)} = \frac{\sum_{h=0}^t \gamma_y(h)}{\gamma_y(0)\sum_{s=0}^t\sum_{h=0}^s \gamma_y(h)}.$$

I am not sure how to continue from this. It seems like it is approximate to some double antiderivative of $\rho(h)$ over its antiderivative, which is like $\frac{\phi^{t+2}}{(t+2)\gamma_y(0)}$ which converges to $0$ for $t$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
corr(x_t,x_{2t})&= \frac{\sum_{h=0}^t \gamma_y(h)}{\gamma_y(0)\sum_{s=0}^t\sum_{h=0}^s \gamma_y(h)}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{h=0}^t \phi^{h}}{\gamma_y(0)\sum_{s=0}^t\sum_{h=0}^s \phi^{h}}\\
&= \frac{\frac{1-\phi^{t+1}}{1-\phi}}{\gamma_y(0)\sum_{s=0}^t\frac{1-\phi^{s+1}}{1-\phi}}\\
&= \frac{1-\phi^{t+1}}{\gamma_y(0)\sum_{s=0}^t (1-\phi^{s+1})}\\
&= \frac{1-\phi^{t+1}}{\gamma_y(0)\left(t+1- \phi \frac{1-\phi^{t+1}}{1-\phi}  \right)}\\
\end{align}$$

If $\phi<1$, the correlation converges to $0$.

If $\phi>1$, the correlation converges to $\frac{1}{\gamma_y(0)\frac{\phi}{1-\phi} }$.

Comment: +1 but what is the meaning of the autocorrelation of y,as you wrote it, when $\phi>1$ and therefore the process is not stationary? Could you help me clarify?

Comment: @Thomas thank you. And in fact, I agree with you that $\phi$ should be smaller than $1$ (in this case the correlation converges to $0$). However, I dont know whether $\phi$ can be greater than 1 in the asker’s question. That’s why I added the second case $\phi>1$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So I guess that the situation is right now that the last step is a bit formal right? Because $\gamma_y(h)$ is not well defined when $\phi>1$, due to the absence of a stationary distribution. For $\phi>1$ probably one should impose some boundary condition (e.g. $y(0)=y_0$), the form of the autocorrelation would change, and the resulting limit could depend on $y_0$ or not, according to what the calculations would say (did not try it out, maybe it gives the same result you obtained).

Comment: Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, just forget the case $\phi >0$, it's an error as the limit becomes negative.